# execute script through rails application in background

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shell

I am writing a script. By this, script I am login to other system through ssh and execute other script that is present on that system.

Here is my code for executing the script

```
def run_script
  system("script/all/myscript")
end
```

here is my script code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f     

spawn ssh -p 11111 admin@localhost
expect "*assword"
send "1234\r"
interact

nohup ./second_script > second_script.out 2> second_script.err < /dev/null | echo $! > second_script_pid.txt &
```

But it is not working as I didn't see any second_script.out and second_script.err files when I logged into that machine?

Did I miss something here?

Comment: have you tested that the script works without ruby???

Comment: how exactly are you executing the script?

Comment: @bjhaid yes I have tested that script without ruby

Comment: @user2622247 try rubys `open3` module to run the script, because it seems tha prroblem is in i/o substsem in the call.

Comment: can you please explain it how?

Comment: IO.popen3 http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3

Comment: `stdin, stdout, stderr,wait_thr = Open3.popen3('nohup sh #{Rails.root}/script/all/myscript.sh')` is right

Comment: what do you mean right?

Comment: did you use exactly the code: `stdin, stdout, stderr,wait_thr = Open3.popen3("nohup '#{Rails.root}/script/all/myscript.sh'")`

Comment: yes, but it not working